# Pass beamer class options to beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes, package-options, class-options

How do I pass the document class options to a beamer theme?

I am writing a beamer theme. I would like to use the beamer class option `aspectratio` to have individual layout settings for the `43` and `169` options. I tried to read the options with `\DeclareOptionBeamer` and `\ProcessOptionsBeamer` in my `sty` file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthememytheme}[2020/03/10]

\newif\ifwidescreen
\widescreenfalse
\DeclareOptionBeamer{aspectratio}[43]{%
    \ifnum#1=169 %
        \widescreentrue%
    \else\ifnum#1=43 %
        \widescreenfalse%
    \fi\fi
}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\mode<presentation>
```

The beamer class option `aspectratio` is not passed to my theme:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{mytheme}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \ifwidescreen%
        16:9
    \else%
        4:3
    \fi
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, it works as expected if I load the theme with the argument `\usetheme[aspectratio=169]{mytheme}`. But I would like that the theme uses the same option as specified in the document class options if no option is provided.

Comment: I changed the title to make it a little clearer

Comment: `beamer` themes can only inherit class options without `=`. `beamer` does this inside macro `\beamer@filterclassoptions`. For example, in usage `\documentclass[key1=val1, key2]{beamer}`, only `key2` is passed to themes. So, do you want a general solution, or 
 a specific way to detect the value passed to `aspectratio`?

Comment: The `aspectratio` option accepts different values : 1610, 169, 149, 141, 54, 43 and 32. Which values should set `\ifwidescreen` to true?

Comment: @PaulGaborit At the moment I am considering 169 and 43 only. So, 169 should set `\ifwidesceen` to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently,

- Usually, LaTeX classes store options in `\@classoptionslist`, and later loaded packages read this macro to inherit options from class.
- However, `beamer` class stores key only options in `\@classoptionslist` (by using macro `\beamer@filterclassoptions`). This means, any class options containing `=`, e.g., `aspectratio=<ratio>`, is filtered out.
- `\ProcessOptionsBeamer` seems to handle key only options, too. (I am not sure.)

The following example provides a workaround to overcome that:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\makeatletter
\AfterPackage{beamerbaseoptions}{%
  % store full class options in \@classoptionslist@full
  \pretocmd{\beamer@filterclassoptions}
    {\let\@classoptionslist@full=\@classoptionslist}
    {}{\fail}%
}
\makeatother

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\makeatletter
% extended \usetheme which inherits key=val class options
\newrobustcmd*\usethemeX[2][]{%
  \let\@classoptionslist=\@classoptionslist@full
  \usetheme[#1]{#2}%
  \let\@classoptionslist=\beamer@filteredclassoptionslist
}

% patch \ProcessOptionsBeamer
\patchcmd{\ProcessOptionsBeamer}
  {\@ifundefined{KV@\@currname @\CurrentOption}}
  {\expandafter\get@key\CurrentOption=\@nil
   \@ifundefined{KV@\@currname @\CurrentOption@key}}
  {}{\fail}
% helper macro
\def\get@key#1=#2\@nil{\def\CurrentOption@key{#1}}
\makeatother

\usethemeX{mytheme}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \ifwidescreen
    16:9
  \else
    4:3
  \fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

By the way, the line containing `\if#1=43` in OP's example should be `\ifnum#1=43`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the workaround! This was more complicated than I expected.

Comment: @luki Hi, I have simplified the workaround, hope that helps.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

With the [current beamer development version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/33672c652c12d7880360ddaa6f7d948285e609d0) (which should be included in beamer v3.70 or newer), one can now use the `\insertaspectratio` macro to access the aspect ratio of the presentation:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\newif\ifwidescreen
\widescreenfalse
\ifnum\insertaspectratio=169 %
    \widescreentrue%
\else\ifnum\insertaspectratio=43 %
    \widescreenfalse%
\fi\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \ifwidescreen%
        16:9
    \else%
        4:3
    \fi
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```